Is the column space of a matrix equal to the dimensional space r, the rank of a matrix A.
Say we have some (m x n) matrix $A$ with rank r = m < n. Then, I know that $A\vec x = \vec b$ can be solved for $\vec x$ with infinitely many solutions. Since rank of the row space is equal to rank of the column space, then I know that dim(C(A)) must equal r = m. Since what is being produced as an output of $A\vec x$ is an (m x 1) vector b, and we know there exists a solution (in this case infinite) for any $\vec b ∈ R^m$, then can I not state that $C(A) = R^m$ ?
That is, can I not say that a column space C(A) of dimension r necessarily spans $R^r$ (since I'm assuming the basis of C(A) must span $R^r$) and therefore must equal $R^r$? Such as in this example: Column space explanation from math.libretexts
Furthermore, can I say that the column space is equal to the row space of $A$: that $C(A) = C(A^T)$? I'm thinking that if so, then it would only be true in the case of a full rank matrix? Since if the rank of A were to be r = m < n, then solving for $A^T\vec x = \vec b$ would not produce the same column space as there would be some (n x 1) vectors b that can't be produced. I guess, to say in other words, in this scenario where m ≠ n, then the dimensions of the vectors produced by the column spaces of $A$ and $A^T$ would be different? Also, is this equivalent in some form to acknowledging that if m ≠ n, then either the row space $C(A^T)$ or the column space $C(A)$ must be embedded within a higher dimension? Thus, they cannot be equal?
Additionally, here https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Linear_Algebra/Matrix_Analysis_(Cox)/03%3A_The_Fundamental_Subspaces/3.01%3A_Column_Space, it talks about essentially considering the range of a matrix as the set of vectors produced by the column space. Then if the range can be said to be a subspace of the output space $W$ which is constrained to be within the rank of the matrix (at least I think so), then does the range (column space, C(A)) only equal the output space $W$ if rank r = m ≤ n?


That is, can I not say that a column space C(A) of dimension r
necessarily spans 

You can say this in the sense that $C(A)$ has dimension $r$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^r$. Just take a basis for the column space, $v_1\dots, v_r$ and consider $e_1,\dots,e_r$ the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^r$. Then define the linear map $T(v_i)=e_i$. This is a bijective linear map and we are done.

Furthermore, can I say that the column space is equal to the row space
of  : that $C(A)=C(A^T)$

This is always true in the sense that the column space is isomorphic to the column space of the transpose (the row space). That is, we can find an invertible linear transformation between the two column spaces. This is always true regardless of the size of the matrix. This follows from the fact that $\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(A^T)$.
Since $\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{col}(A)) =\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(A^T)=\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{col}(A^T))$
then use the fact that finite dimensional vector spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic.
EDIT:
Theorem. Any two vector spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic.
proof.
Let $V$ have basis $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ and $W$ have basis $\{w_1,\dots,w_n\}$.
Define the linear map $T(c_1v_1,\dots,c_nv_n)=c_1w_1,\dots,c_nw_n$.
I can prove that this is bijective if you would like.
A concrete example in your case.
$Col(A) = \operatorname{span}\{[1,2]^T,[3,4]^T \}$.
Define $T(c_1 [1,2]^T + c_2 [3,4]^T) = c_1 [0,1]^T + c_2[0,1]^T$.
This is a bijection so the vector spaces are the same and we write $C(A)\simeq
\mathbb{R}^2$.

Thank you for your knowledge. As for your comment on the bijective linear mapping between the basis vectors of the column space C(A) and $R^r$, say I have the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 3\\ 2 & 4\end{pmatrix}$. Then for the bijective linear map, it would have to be shown that $T(v_i) = e_i$, is that correct? However, I know that trying to add some vector to $v_i$ such that we would try to say $T(v_i) = v_i +  x_i = e_i$ wouldn't work as the transformation  $T(v) = v +  x$  is not linear. Also, to try and say that $T(v_i) = x_iv_i = e_i$ also wouldn't work as $x[1,0]^T  ≠ [1,2]^T$ and

$x*[0,1]^T  ≠ [1,2]^T$. Also, I haven't done much studying on isomorphisms / that field / realm of mappings so I'm unsure if I've misinterpreted the notion of linear here as the same one used for linearity. Thus, I'm a bit confused as to how the bijective linear mapping is achieved between the basis of C(A) and a standard basis for $R^r$. Although, I do believe they produce the same output space (range?).

It holds for any two vector spaces of the same dimension. Any two vector spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic by just identifying their bases together. I think you might be getting caught up too much in the representation of vectors in coordinates and and the abstract vectors themselves which live in vector spaces.

See my edit for a proof in general. Just apply this to the column space and $\mathbb{R}^r$ You will see that as long as you know theyre the same dimension, they're the essentially same vector space so its not worth worrying about.

I see. Is that not a bijection between the combination of the basis for the vector spaces in question? Does that suffice as a bijective mapping for the bases themselves? I think it certainly would make sense to say that $v_i = c_1e_1 + c_2e_2$ <--> $v_i = c_1*[1,0]^T + c_2*[0,1]^T$ but then wouldn't that be showing a bijection between the basis of C(A) and some linear combinations of the standard basis for $R^r$. Now, that I type this out, I think I understand what you meant by typing out $T(c1[1,2]T+c2[3,4]T)=c1[0,1]T+c2[0,1]T$. For some reason I thought you meant there's a strict 1-to-1

mapping between the basis of C(A) and the standard basis for $R^r$. Unless it's by saying that we can use a different function to convert each basis vector of C(A) over to a vector of the standard basis of $R^r$? But I thought the function for the transformation (or just the transformation?) must be applied to and satisfy the 1-to-1 and onto mapping we are trying to establish from the input to the output space. I will say, I think what you said makes sense and I am not disagreeing with it. Right now I'm just debating myself I suppose.

@PizzaPie to define a linear transformation it suffices to define what it does to basis elements I'm not sure what ur question is

I think I understand what you meant now. Thank you!
